# Blank screen shot with Selenium script

Tags: selenium-webdriver

When I open the .jpeg file, it is blank.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\allan\\workspace\\Login\\chromedriver.exe");
            WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
            File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
            FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("C:\\screenshots\\screenshot.jpeg"));


            driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are taking the screenshot even before navigating to any website.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\allan\\workspace\\Login\\chromedriver.exe");
            WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/");
            File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
            FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("C:\\screenshots\\screenshot.jpeg"));   
}
```